# A problem related to probability measures and classes of measurable subsets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of all the probability measures on $\mathcal{A}$. Let moreover $\mathcal{E}$ be a generic subset of $\mathcal{A}$ not containing the empty set. I want to study the number:

$$
\gamma:= \sup_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \inf_{A \in \mathcal{E}} P(A).
$$
This number seems to depend basically on the number and the structure of the intersections among the sets of $\mathcal{E}$. Some examples:

1. If $\mathcal{E}=\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$, with $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, then $\gamma=1/n$;
2. If $\mathcal{E}=\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$, with $A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$ then $\gamma = 1$;
3. If $\mathcal{E}=\{A_1, A_2, A_3\}$, with $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$ but $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3=\emptyset$, then $\gamma = 2/3$.

Can someone find a formule or an algorithm for calculating $\gamma$ in the general case? (In order to simplify the problem the set $\mathcal{E}$ may be considered finite or countable).

Comment: What is the definition of a "generic subset"?

Comment: Any subset or a subset

Comment: Sorry I don't get this. If in your case 1, one of the $A_i$ is the empty set then $P(A_i)=0$ for all probability measures. Then $\gamma$ should be zero. Also: what is the *context* of this question?

Comment: You are right, the empty set must be excluded from $\mathcal{E}$. Basically I am interested in understanding the structure of $\mathcal{E}$ allowing $\gamma \approx 1$. For example, if $\mathcal{E}$ contains two disjoint sets then $\gamma \leq 1/2$.